# The target type of expression must be a functional interface – why is this needed?

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-errors, java-8, functional-interface

I have gone through lots of questions which have the same headline but I didn't get the answer I am looking for.

In `Greeter` class below there is a simple sysout. As I understand it, what lambda cares about is the signature (i.e. return type and no. of parameters). But if i remove

> int add(int a);

it perfectly works, because compiler will check that there is any method available in `Greeting` interface which has no arguments and whose return type is void.

But when I keep that method there, I get the compilation error mentioned in subject line, as per my understanding compiler will go to `Greeting` interface and it will see there are two methods. However there should be no ambiguity because my lambda expression looks for the method whose return type is void and only one argument. Based on this analogy there is only one method so ideally it should not give error.

I know that my analogy is wrong here, I do know that it must be a functional interface, but I also think that the process which I have mentioned above is exactly how the compiler is going to work.

Can anyone please let me know where I am wrong and how the compiler is actually working in my example?

**Greeting Interface**

```
package lambadas;

public interface Greeting {
    void perform();
    int add(int a);
}
```

**Greeter class**

```
package lambadas;

public class Greeter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greeting l = () -> System.out.println("hello");
        l.perform();
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldGreeting**

```
package lambadas;

public class HelloWorldGreeting implements Greeting {

    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("hello world.!");
    }
    @Override
    public int add(int a) {
      return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Greeting is not a functional interface. It must have only one method without body.

Comment: yes, exactly why lambada needs functional interface.?

Comment: It is probably because you are creating anonymous instance of class which try to implements you interface. Your lambda covers only one method, so compiler shows error

Comment: `HelloWorldGreeting` does not actualy implement `Greeting` since it is lacking a method defined in the interface.

Comment: done the changes in the question , doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @diwakarbhatt Well, there is a huge difference since `HelloWorldGreeting` now provides an implementation of the `add(int)` method, whereas the lambda still does not.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your efforts and views for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start by asking yourself this question: if it was possible to implement `Greeting` that way, what would happen when calling `l.add(0)`? `NoSuchMethodError`? Undefined behaviour? You probably don't want that – and the language designers didn't want it either.

By enforcing functional interfaces as target types for lambda expressions, the compiler guarantees that you don't have partial implementations of those interfaces. This is exactly the same reason as for the compiler error you would get if `HelloWorldGreeting` did not implement `add(int)` either: you provide 1 implementation, but there are 2 methods to implement.

So this is not really about matching your lambda with a specific method, but instead it is about creating valid instances of the interface it implements.

Comment: the question is here that, the moment i define more than one method in an interface lambada expression gives compilation error, 
its because the interface must be functional interface, i got this part.
issue is why, how the compiler is working, what i have read in various place that lambada doesn't care about the name of the interface , what it cares that the interface must have the method which matches the lambada expression signature(i.e. type and parameters)

Comment: if i define int add(int a); it suddenly gives error, if i ignore the same lambada working fine. I am confused that if its only about signature than compiler can easily find the unique method which had void type and no parameters because there is only one such method.

Comment: @diwakarbhatt It is NOT about the signature of the method implemented by the lambda. My answer explains why you need a functional interface – a.k.a. single abstract method (SAM) interface. If you add a second abstract method, it is not a SAM interface anymore. Could you indicate more precisely which part of the answer you don't understand? I'll be happy to clarify if needed.

Comment: The second part **By enforcing functional interfaces as target types for lambda expressions** , you are right about that the moment I define another interface it's not an functional interface(SAM).
Why we need functional interface for lambada to work, i got the point that that's how it has been done by oracle.
when I write lambada expression _Greeting l = () -> System.out.println("hello");_ what is exactly happening in background.
what does compiler do after that it identifies that return type is Greeting?
regarding that i am not implementing add()  method.

Comment: Functional interfaces were not introduced out of choice but out of necessity. Your lambda only provides code for 1 method, but it would need to implement an interface with 2 abstract methods. How would that work? It cannot. That's why the compiler checks that the implemented interface is a functional one (i.e. exactly 1 abstract method).

Comment: Correct me if i wrong, my understanding with your comments is that the  lambada is acting like class which has to implement all the methods for the interface(targeting type) which is not possible at all in a single lambada expression, that's why we are saying that target type must be functional interface because the lambda act as a function and it's an implementation of the method in interface.

Comment: Yes, that's it :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for being patience with my questions :-) , I got my answers.

Comment: @diwakar bhatt: since you’re constantly misspelling it: “lambada” is a dance, what your question is about, are *lambda* expressions.

Comment: @DidierL: even if all interface methods were `default` methods, i.e. no risk of ending up with an incomplete implementation, a compiler will never guess about which method to implement. The compiler will already “guess” about the lambda expression’s actual signature based on the target type’s functional signature and also guessing the other way round, about the actual functional signature (method to implement) based on the lambda expression would end up in too much guesswork. And lambdas are *not* meant to be a feature for easy interface implementations, that’s only an integration workaround.

Comment: @Holger indeed, I didn't cover the case of 0 abstract methods as I felt it was not really part of the question and I don't know what one would expect from that case.

Comment: I had the feeling, the OP would expect that the lambda expression overrides the method with a matching signature.

Answer (score 5):

Annotate your interface with `@FunctionalInterface` - and see it breaking.  Only a *single* abstract method is allowed.

Comment: obviously, it will break because its not functional interface. again if you go through the question my context is different. why compiler needs functional interface lambada to work.?

Comment: @diwakarbhatt right, it just that your question was a bit confusing... what you are saying *might* have been a valid point - they just decided not to. This had it's pluses and minuses  - I can't tell the exact reasons for it though .